# Serving different css box shadows for different browsers without browser detection?

Tags: javascript, css, html, stylesheet, browser-detection

I noticed that each browsers renders box shadow blur radius slightly different so I want to even that out. However, as they use the unprefixed version I need to serve different stylesheets for different browsers. What is the most reliable method?

For example: Mozilla uses `moz_style.css`, Chrome uses `chrome_style.css`

Im doing this using user agent detection but I heared it is not very reliable:

```
<script>
if(BrowserDetect.browser=="Chrome") {
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chrome.css" type="text/css" media="all" />')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does it *really* matter that there's a 1px difference between browsers?  Do you think Firefox users will get out a magnifying glass and say "holy crap, this isn't a pixel perfect match to Chrome"?

Comment: These differences should fade away by time and browsers updates passing by :)

Comment: You don't need any browser detection. Just keep care you're creating great looking pages. If they're looking slightly different in each browser, so what? Users of those browsers are used to see things in a certain way, please don't try to change it.

Comment: @cimmanon I got my website to show pixel perfect and identical on mac, pc and all browsers. Literaly pixel perfect, even the fonts. I also fixed the box shadows but I just need to find out how to target the different css. Right now im just using browser detection. Works well but I prefer a different method.

Answer (score 0):

Surely box-shadow as a CSS property already makes use of vendor prefixes for a few different browsers. If you take a look at this random box-shadow snippet I pulled from elsewhere on the web you'll see that it uses different declarations for webkit, firefox on top of the primary box shadow property:

```
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
```

I know for example that the Opera vendor prefix is -o so you may be able to append that vendor prefix to the box shadow property to cover Opera browsers although I am not sure if it's supported. Also you have IE specific box shadow rules as well:

```
.ieShadow{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    right:-5px;
    bottom:-5px;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=5)";
    background-color:#444;
}
```

Browser "Sniffing" with Javascript is not seen to be the way go anymore to detect browsers.

So yes all in all, surely your box shadow code can just vary from one vendor prefixed property to another?

**EDIT:** Some enlightenment on the subject reveals that it really isn't all that simple. Vendor prefixes are a bit of a mess really.

This gives you a good idea of the browsers using the webkit engine and the main box-shadow property:

```
.box_shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ffffff; /* Android 2.3+, iOS 4.0.2-4.2, Safari 3-4 */
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ffffff; /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 4+, IE 9+, iOS 5+, Opera 10.50+ 
}
```

So I guess specific browser targeting is not achievable with vendor prefixes in CSS (??!)

Comment: hi adaam, arent vendor prefixes going to be removed? I mean as far as I know modern mozilla and chrome dont read those anymore or am I wrong?

Comment: Just about every browser is prefix free on box-shadow.  Even if some browsers still retain the prefixed version along side the non-prefixed version, the last line overwrites it.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

Comment: I was just about to post an interesting comparison.. I'll edit my answer

Comment: @adaam absolutely. I mean it works if we add  "important" for overriding. However it is a little risky as prefixes werent designed for that purpose and might become ineffective sooner or later. I would remove all prefixes but it is really unsafe as some users still browse with older versions of mozilla and chrome.

Comment: @Damian I just found a really good article you should read about cross browser compatibility (http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/). It mentions using Modernizr which is also a good idea that hasn't been mentioned yet

Comment: @adaam cool, I heared some really good things about modernizer. What I dont understand about it though is how feature detection can be used to serve different stylesheets for different browsers.